# Updating bokeh patches in Jupiter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, bokeh

I am curious about the right way to update the Patches glyph in bokeh. 
My minimal example is:

```
p_blur = figure(x_range=(0, 300), y_range=(0, 300))
source = ColumnDataSource({'xs':[[100,200,300], [10,50,500,400]], 'ys':[[30,150,70], [10,500,50,50]]})
polygons = Patches(xs="xs", ys="ys",fill_color="#fb9a99")
glyph = p_blur.add_glyph(source, polygons)
nb = show(p_blur, notebook_handle=True)
```

If I now want to update the glyph e.g. by

```
source1 = ColumnDataSource({'xs':[[10,20,30], [10,50,50,40]], 'ys':[[30,15,70], [10,50,50,50]]})
glyph.data_source = source1
push_notebook( nb )
```

I don't see any change. However, if I do:

```
p_blur.renderers.remove(glyph)
glyph = p_blur.add_glyph(source1, polygons)
push_notebook( nb )
```

The change is reflected. Seems though that the second way is too hacky. Is there more correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign new data to `source.data`, try this:

```
source.data = {'xs':[[10,20,30], [10,50,50,40]], 'ys':[[30,15,70], [10,50,50,50]]}
push_notebook(nb)
```